# why does 'a'..'z' in ANTLR match wildcards like $ or £

Tags: lexer, antlr3, ebnf

When I run the following grammer:

```
test : WORD+;

WORD : ('a'..'z')+;
WS : ' '+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

and I give the input "?test" why does antlr accept this as valid input? I thought the ('a'..'z') would only match characters within the lowercase alphabet?

Comment: I also thought that. Are you sure ? Are you saying that "?test" is parsed as  WORD token ?

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening. I'm using the antlr3 IDE for eclipse to test it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR *does* produce an error when parsing the input string `?test` with the grammar you posted. As is usually the case, the error lies with the tool being used around ANTLR (I see it happen a lot with ANTLRWorks as well, unfortunately!).

To test it yourself (properly), create a file `Test.g`:

```
grammar Test;

test : WORD+;

WORD : ('a'..'z')+;

WS   : ' '+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

and a file `Main.java`:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("?test");
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        parser.test();
    }
}
```

and download a copy of the [ANTLR 3.2 JAR](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-3.2.jar) in the same directory.

Now generate a lexer & parser:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Test.g
```

compile all Java source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

and run the Main class:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main
```

*(replace the `:` with `;` if you're on Windows!)*

which will produce the following error message:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at character '?'
```